# Removing Ubuntu's Privacy Breaching Features

Tags: bash, zeitgeist

I want to remove all tracking features from Ubuntu in a single line (or a few) lines of Bash script. Is this enough or am I missing something:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip geoip-database whoopsie
```

The target is Ubuntu LTS.

Definition of Privacy Breaching to me:

1. Trackers
2. Anything that provides my geo-location to an website
3. Any back-end advertisement tracking etc.

Basically, I am open to suggestions as well and please do not consider my code as a hard and fast solution.

Comment: Define privacy breaching. Is a local eventlog disturbing privacy in any meaningful way? How is a geolocation tool privacy breaching? It just provides a lookup table...

Comment: Done - edited question.

Comment: It's still wide open. Zeitgeist tracks local events, and does not submit the logs anywhere. Same goes for a lot of system logs. The website geo location can be disabled in browsers, and is a browser feature, not installed packages. IP-based geo-location is a server feature, and not something you can disable on your side... It's unclear whom you're protecting against, and what you are targeting. Is it a remote attacker, or someone that steals your computer?

Comment: @vidarlo yes you are right. context is, if I ever get an infection or someone steals the PC, this should not be traceable to me. I know Linux virus is extremely rare and far in-between but just in case.

Comment: Full disk encryption will take care of the case where the PC's stolen. If you get malware, the malware can likely track your use anyway, so focusing on avoiding malware would make more sense...

Comment: @vidarlo I think your comments explaining what the packages the OP wants to get rid of are actually doing and questioning the usefulness of removing them for privacy reasons would make an excellent answer.

Comment: "all tracking features" seems to me rather fearmongery and misleading. The erroneous underlying assumption that there are deliberate tracking features in the first place makes this question seemingly unfixable. A better question would be more neutral: "What information does Ubuntu collect, to whom is it sent, and which of it can be tracked back to me?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub python-zeitgeist

  - Zeitgeist is a event logging system. By default it does not send any information away from the computer. It may not be useful to you, in which case you can remove it, but it won't really change privacy level, unless the computer has shared accounts.
- geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip

  - This is a service for making position available to other D-Bus applications. It does not transmit any information.
- geoip-database

  - This is merely a database over geographical areas for IP-ranges. It's not a tool. It's a database. It does not transmit anything about you, nor does it contain any information that a remote web site does not see anyway when you connect.
- whoopsie

  - This is an error tracker. It sends error reports. It asks first. If you don't use it, feel free to uninstall it, but it doesn't really invade your privacy to any great extent.

You also mention anything that provides your location to websites. There's roughly two techniques used for this - [Geolocation-API in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) and your public IP. Browsers ask before revealing your location to remote sites, and it can be disabled in the browsers configuration if you want.

Your public IP reveals which region you're in, and is not terribly accurate. You can't disable that - only way around it is to use a proxy or a VPN service.

You mention protecting against theft and malware. Against theft, Full Disk Encryption will be very effective. The thief will not be able to access the data you store on your device. Against malware, keeping up to date and not running software not from repositories is probably the best advise. In addition, uninstalling the packages you list won't really change the chance of being infected.

Uninstalling zeitgeist may make the *privacy impact* of malware less, if some malware were to extract information from zeitgeist. If you don't use zeitgeist, uninstall it, by all means, but your rationale seems strange.

Comment: Thank you very much - that is a very detailed answer.

Comment: Rather than start with the premise, start with which attacks you want to protect against, and work out how to defend against those attacks. Maybe removing `zeitgeist` is a good move in some scenarios, but it's not universally true :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also remove the weblaunchers which include amazon:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-web-launchers
```

Comment: This package is completely harmless and there's not the slightest reason to cause fear about it. All it contains is a couple .desktop files, icons and a small Python helper script that uses geoclue to determine your location country and decide which local amazon web page to open in the browser. There is nothing intrusive about it. Check the sources if you want. You can of course remove it if you don't want that functionality, but there si no reason to remove it out of fear of a "privacy breach" or spyware or however you want to call it.