# is ubunut and all the stuff come with it 100% privacy friendly

Tags: gnome, security, privacy

i **love** **Linux** *and* **Ubuntu** for the easy and fast user experience and i come from windows to Linux for another reason which is **privacy ** i care about privacy and my biggest fear in life is when my privacy is not safe, so i need to know is Ubuntu safe, can i store sensitive data on my Ubuntu without and problems and what about gnome the desktop environment of Ubuntu ? **can i trust gnome** or should i change my desktop environment for privacy and last question **is all Linux desktop environment safe in term of privacy and if not what the best Linux desktop environment** , thanks for all answers in advanced i wish the best for Ubuntu and Linux community

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask . This question seems both unresearched, vague, and asks too many questions at once. Do your research, then ask a specific, answerable question. Different folks have different definitions of "privacy" and "secure" so be sure your specific question is very clear.

Comment: Nothing is 100% anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Ubuntu's Privacy Breaching Features](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144988/removing-ubuntus-privacy-breaching-features)

Comment: @karel thank you so much, i was looking for how to disable any network connection that track me, and you help little bit, thank you again, and if you have more useful links share it here please.

Answer (score 1):

very much so.  the linux  community in general are people who are ferocious about privacy.  There are scads of them who tear every bit of software  produced apart looking for trouble.
I know it seems to good to be true, all this software and  functionality and no one is trying to make you into the product to sell your information to market to you.
But this one time, in all gin joints in all the world, this time it is true.

Comment: thanks for answer, how can i check linux utility tracking on me ( i mean how to see if some package is connects to network and what data it send) i know that firewall can disable the connection, but i don't know how to check for network connection of some package in ubuntu by name for example vim, again thank you for answer

Comment: That is exactly the sort of question a SYSOP needs to answer.  "Who has access?"   Who is using?"  "For What?"  In Microsoft windows or apple the consumer never actually has those answers.  They simply have to trust the integrity of strangers.   In modern Linux using the GUI interface you still have that but, you will also be encouraged to learn use the command line.  I suggest you start with the book  "The Linux Command Line"  by W. Shotts.  It's inexpensive and  easy to read and understand.  with  that book you will learn to answer  your questions.